# Error in Flutter App while implementing youtube player

Tags: flutter, youtubeplayer

Please find the below Error:

Compiler message:
../lib/youtube_player.dart:1175:31: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isInitialRoute'.
      settings: RouteSettings(isInitialRoute: false),
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/CreativeWork/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:419:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RouteSettings({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Circular dependency between the following tasks:
  :youtube_player:generateDebugRFile
  --- :youtube_player:generateDebugRFile (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Sateesh Reddy\Downloads\sarbagyastha-youtube_player-v3.1.1-11-g1850147\sarbagyastha-youtube_player-1850147\android\build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  Could not get unknown property 'ANDROIDX_WARNING' for project ':youtube_player' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as well, Check if you were using this package https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player

If thats what you were using, it was discontinued, use this instead

https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter/install